# Finding the variable stored in exponent

Tags: logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have the following equation where I'm trying to re-write in terms of $X$ (ie:  $X = ....$)

I understand I need to take the natural log of the equation to extract the $X$ out of the left-side, but then I am left over with the natural log of $X$ from the right-side

$A(6.112e^\dfrac{17.67*X}{243.5+X}) = B - C(X-D)$

- $e$ = euler's number (~2.718)
- $A, B, C, D$ are all known

Comment: Is that really $\frac{17.67X}{243.5X}$ in the exponent?  If so then they'll cancel out, essentially making this a linear equation in $X$.

Comment: No its not. I just edited the equation. its a "+" in the denominator. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I have seen people using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function for solving similar equations, although I am not sure it applies here and are not confident with the subject. In any case, it is clear that no elementary expression for $X$ exists. I would suggest solving it numerically.

Comment: you can extract a constant from the e243.5, then rearrange to aXexp(X) + bX + cExp(X) + d = 0, then Newton Raphson Method

Comment: Yes, this will require the Lambert W function, if that would work here at all.  Don't know if I've seen it applied when the exponent is a rational function of $x$.  In any case, numerically solving is the way to go.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid an iterative method...but I think you guys are right.